# How to change checkbox "checked" icon

Tags: c#, checkbox, icons, state, checked

As I know checkbox can have not only 2 states but also 3. But third state is full filled box. I need to have 3 states in checkbox: unchecked, checked with checkmark (like default), and checked with cross (like this: http://petromi.com/get/ade59e55c1.png).

How to do like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ThreeState Property of CheckBox Control to true as below:

```
checkBox1.ThreeState=true;
```

ThreeStae CheckBox has following 3 States:

1. Unchecked
2. Checked
3. Indeterminate

Answer (score 0):

The regular `checkbox` in winforms has only 2 states: Checked=> `true` or `false`; If you want to have a third state you have to implement it yourself. You could create a new costum checkbox and add the thrid state with events and all you ever want. This may helps http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2016/Writing-your-Custom-Control-step-by-step.